# RASA X: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character when run Rasa X

Tags: rasa, rasa-x

I am using Rasa Open Source to build a chatbot application and it works pretty well. I want to use Rasa X to make more use of its features. But I get this problem every time I run the command `rasa x`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\admin\anaconda3\envs\chatbot3\lib\site-packages\rasax\community\services\story_service.py", line 212, in get_story_steps
    return StoryService._reader_read_from_string(reader, story_string)
  File "c:\users\admin\anaconda3\envs\chatbot3\lib\site-packages\rasax\community\services\story_service.py", line 130, in _reader_read_from_string
    f.write(story_string)
  File "c:\users\admin\anaconda3\envs\chatbot3\lib\tempfile.py", line 481, in func_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\admin\anaconda3\envs\chatbot3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u1ee7' in position 25: character maps to <undefined>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\admin\anaconda3\envs\chatbot3\lib\site-packages\rasa\cli\x.py", line 500, in run_locally
    domain_path=domain_path,
  File "c:\users\admin\anaconda3\envs\chatbot3\lib\site-packages\rasax\community\local.py", line 242, in main
    project_path, data_path, session, args.port, config_path, domain_path
  File "c:\users\admin\anaconda3\envs\chatbot3\lib\site-packages\rasax\community\local.py", line 169, in _initialize_with_local_data
    domain_path=domain_path,
  File "c:\users\admin\anaconda3\envs\chatbot3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 579, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "c:\users\admin\anaconda3\envs\chatbot3\lib\site-packages\rasax\community\initialise.py", line 375, in inject_files_from_disk
    username,
  File "c:\users\admin\anaconda3\envs\chatbot3\lib\site-packages\rasax\community\initialise.py", line 135, in inject_stories
    story_files, team, project_id, username
  File "c:\users\admin\anaconda3\envs\chatbot3\lib\site-packages\rasax\community\services\story_service.py", line 553, in save_stories_from_files
    is_test=is_test,
  File "c:\users\admin\anaconda3\envs\chatbot3\lib\site-packages\rasax\community\services\story_service.py", line 434, in save_stories
    story_string, filename, domain, is_test
  File "c:\users\admin\anaconda3\envs\chatbot3\lib\site-packages\rasax\community\services\story_service.py", line 332, in _extract_stories_markdown
    test_stories=is_test,
  File "c:\users\admin\anaconda3\envs\chatbot3\lib\site-packages\rasax\community\services\story_service.py", line 216, in get_story_steps
    "'{}'\nError: {}".format(story_string, e)
rasa.shared.core.training_data.story_reader.story_reader.StoryParseError
```

I tried using rasa x and it seems to be perfect for English. But my current language is Vietnamese. Does rasa x have a problem with it?

Someone please help me!

***UPDATE***

I fixed the charmap bug and start the bot successfully, but something went wrong making the conversation not so smooth.

```
WARNING:rasax.community.services.event_consumers.event_consumer:Saving event failed due to an 'IntegrityError'.
An error occured when trying to send the telemetry event: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.segment.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/track (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 500 Internal Server Error')))
```

Comment: Hi @Phúc Nguyễn , welcome to stackoverflow! If you find an answer to your own question, it is good practice to add it as an answer yourself, to make it easier for others to find. Here you could add an answer explaining how you fixed the charmap bug.
It's better to then add a new question for the subsequent, different problem, since it no longer matches the original description. 
Happy asking and answering!

Answer (score 0):

This warning:

```
An error occured when trying to send the telemetry event: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.segment.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/track (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 500 Internal Server Error')))
```

Is not a problem that should impact the bot; it is only saying it tried to send telemetry events but could not. Telemetry events aren't things your bot/Rasa X needs to operate. Unless it causes an actual issue with the bot, you can ignore it.